# Failed to run custom build command for `libgpg-error-sys v0.6.0` when cross compiling rust project using cross

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

Whenever I try to cross compile my rust project on my Machine running arch linux, using cross for the `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` architecture I get this error

```
$ cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu                                                                                                                         
   Compiling tracing v0.1.37
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.7
   Compiling rand_core v0.5.1
   Compiling libgpg-error-sys v0.6.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `libgpg-error-sys v0.6.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/debug/build/libgpg-error-sys-49b8c1a22a8cb06e/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=GPG_ERROR_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  Error: PkgConfig(`PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "gpg-error" "gpg-error >= 1.12"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'gpg-error' required by the 'libgpg-error-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  Package gpg-error was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gpg-error.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'gpg-error' found
  Package gpg-error was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gpg-error.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'gpg-error' found
  )
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

I have `gpgme = "0.11.0"` as a dependency in my `Cargo.toml` file

- I reinstalled the `libgpg-error` package
- Tried adding the output of `pkg-config --path gpg-error` to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable as well. The output of `pkg-config --path gpg-error` is `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/gpg-error.pc`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

> sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get install -y libgpgme-dev && sudo apt-get install -y libgpg-error-dev

Then restart the terminal.

Comment: It worked for me too, but no need to restart terminal

Comment: But I got this problem without any cross compilation. So I guess this just adds what is needed for the gpgme crate.